# intent-filter android restart app if app running

Tags: java, android, android-intent, serial-port, intentfilter

I am writing an application that uses a serial port.

this is how my xml looks like

```
<application>
    ...
    <activity>
        ...
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
            
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
    </intent-filter>
            
    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
            
    </activity>        
</application>
```

when connecting a usb device, the smartphone prompts me to select my default application.

I give permission to use it and remember the choice.

But if I switch the usb device when the application is running, then when connected, the application will restart ...

How can this be avoided?

I am expecting the following behaviour.

1. If the application is not running, then when connected, it starts
2. If the application is running, then when connected, the application continues to work, but will be notified about the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Add the android:launchMode="singleTop" attribute to the associated activity

```
<application>
    ...
    <activity>
        ...
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        ...
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
            
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
    </intent-filter>
            
    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
            
    </activity>        
</application>
```